# AngularJS + Fabric.js: Canvas object:selected events do not fire after route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, routes, fabricjs

When interacting with canvas on a fresh page reload everything works fine.  I can select images, move them around, add them etc.  However, when I navigate away from the page to another route and return to the URL with the canvas, object:select events on the canvas are no longer fired.  Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Can you select objects after route change?
Jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: No, you can not select objects but you do get mouse events with a null target.  Unfortunately it's tough to create a fiddle to emulate route changes.  I was able to resolve the issue by making the call canvas.calcOffset() after loading the canvas from json.  However, I have no idea why this works.  Thoughts?